# Check OctoberCMS Version

Tags: octobercms

I have installed [octobercms](/questions/tagged/octobercms) and I want to check version number of my current installed [octobercms](/questions/tagged/octobercms).

How can I check via Command line,through **backend** (*after login*) and through any file?

Comment: This definitely needs to get more coverage in 2019. I spent ages looking for the version number because I thought it should be easy to find and didn't want to Google for it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into the `Backend -> Settings -> Updates & Plugins` you will find `Current Build` number

Answer (score -1):

Login into your backend and add a widget system status on your dashboard and here you can check your system build version.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S27ge.png)